# Angular: Date Conversion

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I convert **"2017-11-09T21:59:22.000Z"** to  "**01.01.2018 00:00:00**" using Angular 2/4.

and vice versa : "**01.01.2018 00:00:00**" to  **"2017-11-09T21:59:22.000Z"**.

I'm using primeNG calendar with showtime as the input source for the date

I basically need to convert that date format as my backend endpoint accepts a different format

Comment: This question is odd.... I'm *assuming* that you are trying to ask how to convert from one format to another, and don't really care that your source and expected values aren't even close to the same...... how would you convert `11/9/2017` to `1/1/2018`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://momentjs.com/

it would be something like

```
moment('2017-11-09T21:59:22.000Z').format('DD.MM.YYYY SS:MM:HH')
```